# How to draw a rectangle in a diagram? (pfgplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw such a rectangle. -> [image]

1. Empty One
2. Crosshatching

Thank you in advance.

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    %\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{semilogxaxis}
        [
            enlarge x limits=false,
            no marks,
            grid=none,
            xmin=1e4, xmax=22260785,
            ymin=0, ymax=120,
            ylabel={$\sigma_{a}$},
            xlabel={$N$},
            samples=400 
         ]
           \begin{scope}[green] 
             \draw[orange,dashed] ({axis cs:50045,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({axis cs:50045,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
             \draw[dashed,green] ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,18.385735235}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,18.385735235});
           \end{scope}
      \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, knowing about `axis cs` and `rel axis cs` you're kind of halfway to the solution. Note that if you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` or higher, `axis cs` is default, so you don't have to specify it.

Anyways, to draw a rectangle, use

```
\draw (x1,y1) rectangle (x2,y2);
```

To fill a rectangle with diagonal lines, add `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}`, and

```
\fill [pattern=north east lines] (x1,y1) rectangle (x2,y2);
```

`pattern=north west lines` will give you lines tilted the other way. If you want to draw the border as well, use `\filldraw`, change the color of the border with `draw=<color>`.

To cross hatch the lower left corner for example, you can use

```
\filldraw [draw=red,pattern=north east lines] (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (50045,18.385735235);
```

Note that if `compat` is set to `1.10` or lower, or you have a version of `pgfplots` that is older than 1.11, you have to use `axis cs:` for the second coordinate, i.e.

```
\filldraw [draw=red,pattern=north east lines] (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:50045,18.385735235);
```

Some other examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} %don't need axis cs: with 1.11 or higher
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}
    [
        enlarge x limits=false,
        no marks,
        grid=none,
        xmin=1e4, xmax=22260785,
        ymin=0, ymax=120,
        ylabel={$\sigma_{a}$},
        xlabel={$N$},
        samples=400 
     ]

         \draw[orange,dashed] ({50045,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({50045,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
         \draw[dashed,green] ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{0,18.385735235}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{0,18.385735235});

         \filldraw [draw=red,pattern=north east lines] (1e5,20) rectangle (1e6,40);
         \draw [thick,blue] (1e6,40) rectangle (1e7,60);
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```